# angularjs: modify model in event trigger function in directive will take effect at first time, why?

Tags: angularjs, directive

First, this is a demo on plunk: [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxv4QDpYfPYAAF0mfNfq?p=preview)

Code:

html:

```
<counter></counter>
<hr>
<counter2></counter2>
```

js:

```
directiveSlideShare.directive('counter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="assignCounter()">assign 0 to counter</a><button>increse counter</button><div>{{counter}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.assignCounter = function() {
        scope.counter = 1;
      }
      ele.find('button').on('click', function() {
        if (!scope.counter) {
          alert("please click 'assign' button first");
          return;
        }
        console.log(scope.counter);
        // this will never being applied
        scope.counter++;
      });
    }
  };
});

directiveSlideShare.directive('counter2', function() {
  return {
      template: 'test: <input ng-model="test" type="text" ng-focus="noticeUser()"><span>{{noticeStr}}</span><div>value of test(will update when blur): <span id="domEvil"></span></div>',
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
          var count = 0;
          scope.noticeUser = function() {
              scope.noticeStr = "count" + (!count ? "" : (" +" + count));
              count++;
          };
          ele.find('input').on('change', function() {
              document.querySelector('#domEvil').textContent = scope.test;
              // This will being applied at first time???
              scope.noticeStr = '';
              console.warn(scope.noticeStr);
          });
      }
  };
});
```

In counter, first I click `assign ...` button to assign `1` to `scope.counter`, and then I click `increase..` button to increase `scope.counter`, as expected, the view will not being updated.

Then I focus the `test input`, this will trigger `$digest` to run, I guess so(appreciate if anyone can explain the real thing happen here ^_^), then the view of `scope.counter` is being updated. And at the same time, `noticeUser` will be called. `noticeStr` will be assigned and update its view.

After I enter something and then blur, the `test input` will trigger `change` event, and the function will be called which assign empty string to `scope.noticeStr`, **this will update the view this time, and become empty. why??** Then when you repeat these(focus the input, enter something, blur the input), the view of `scope.noticeStr` will not be updated even though its value being changed which is expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the 'onClick' or 'onChange' handler, you are using the DOM events and not telling Angular to 'watch' for these events and thus whatever happens inside these handlers is not part of the '$digest' cycle.

Instead, use `ng-click` and `ng-change` to do what you want, like in this modified plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/1dLYWZJ97iYyGDwBhXSg?p=preview

The reason for the update in 'why' of your question is because of the `ng-focus` thats on your input.  Thats triggering a digest cycle that then updates the view on the first to the currently incremented value.

Comment: but why I `focus` input and type something, then blur. `digest cycle` won't be trigger again?

Comment: It should.  What behavior do you see which makes you think that the digest cycle is not triggered again?

Comment: `scope.noticeStr = '';` this will be executed when blur; But the view reflect to `notcieStr` will not be empty except first time.

Comment: The reason for this is the same - the event that triggers this change is not triggering or happening in the digest cycle and thus doesn't reflect on the view.  If you do an `ng-change` instead, it will.